# My Diffuse node is broken. Can't change color, as it just gets capped

Tags: materials, color

does anyone know why my blender caps my material color picker? http://prntscr.com/mp0l56 I can't make the color more saturated than this? I can't even color pick, I color picked her dress and it just picks a color no where close to it http://prntscr.com/mp0ksi  Adjusting the brightness of the purple also just desaturates it to white instantly http://prntscr.com/mp0ljd

http://prntscr.com/mp0mzf http://prntscr.com/mp0n3c it just starts curving up to the blue

http://prntscr.com/mp0n8o

and gets capped at .838

http://prntscr.com/mp0nde and if i try to adjust the hue http://prntscr.com/mp0nh7 it just instantly changes the saturation to white

video https://youtu.be/yODr51F2xgo

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they appear as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: As mentioned by cegaton, please edit your question to include the images using the tools on the site rather than external links. This makes the question easier to read (as the images are visible) as well as making the question remain meaningful if the images are removed from the external site.
As for your problem, do you have any Blender Add-ons activated that might cause the problem? Does the problem exist in a 'default' fresh Blend file? Do other nodes (eg, Emission Shader) and color pickers also have the same problem?